# Symfony4 + deploy project

Tags: php, php-deployer

I encounter an error when I try to deploy with php deployer. Here is the error that I meet:

> Extracting archive  - Installing symfony/web-link (v4.1.4): Loading from cache
>      Extracting archiveGenerating optimized autoload files
>   post-install-cmd: @auto-scripts
>     Executing script cache:clear
>     Executed script cache:clear  [KO]
>      [KO]
>     Script cache:clear returned with error code 255
>     !!  PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught RuntimeException: APP_ENV environment variable is not defined. You need to define environment variables for configuration or add "symfony/dotenv" as a
>     Composer dependency to load variables from a .env file. in /home/projet/www/beta/releases/1/bin/console:20
>     !!  Stack trace:
>     !!  #0 {main}
>     !!    thrown in /home/projet/www/beta/releases/1/bin/console on line 20
>     !!

Should we configure something more to deploy in prod and dev?

Thank you for help.

Comment: You need to either set environment variables on your server, or create an `.env` file in your project root (and install symfony/dotenv as described). The docs should cover what you need to know - I recommend reading the relevant docs and familiarise yourself with your options.

Comment: This is probably a good starting point: https://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration.html

Comment: I wish I could do this dynamically how to do it if I have to go through the server? thank you

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by dynamically - can you elaborate?

Comment: I use deploy php to deploy my project to have 2 environments dev and prod. I was able to solve the problem above but now I have another problem when I'm in production. When my variable APP_DEBUG = 1 my production environment is working and when APP_DEBUG = 0 I have an error 404 Not found